# How to hide 'note: ... ' gcc output for external headers?

Tags: c++, gcc

I try to compile my testproject with gcc 4.8.5. To exclude a warning messages from third-party code I put all external headers into my header - external.h:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
...
#include "Object.h"
...
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

This works fine for warnings, but I see in gcc output many messages like below:

```
In file included from /home/testuser/testproject/external.h:26:0,
             from /home/testuser/testproject/main.cpp:14:
/home/testuser/externallib/Object.h: In instantiation of ‘int ObjectImpl<T_Class, T_Type, T_Size>::addChild(IObj*, unsigned int) [with T_Class = Shape; ObjType T_Type = (ObjType)12u; unsigned int T_Size = 20u:
/home/testuser/externallib/Object.h:1618:43:   required from here
/home/testuser/externallib/Object.h:817:5: note: declarations in dependent base ‘ObjBase’ are not found by unqualified lookup
/home/testuser/externallib/Object.h:817:5: note: use ‘this->get_Obj’ instead
```

...

Unfortunately, I can't change the third-party code to hide that messages. Could anyone provide a way how to hide 'note:' messages when project builds? This will make my build-logs more clean :). Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like an error though, not a warning. Why do you want to remove a helpful error log to help debug the error?

Comment: You may try to add directory for `Object.h`  through -system instead of -I that would suppress warnings

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yes, this look like error but compiles and works fine. I want to hide these notes because I afraid to miss an important warning or note in my own code.

Comment: @Slava Thanks for your participation! Unfortunately, this not working for me. I tried -isystem in gcc options and also include_directories(SYSTEM ...) in cmake. Possible it not working because note is not a warning.

Comment: @serega.mpa where did I say `-isystem` ? Enable verbose mode in camke, it is possible directory for Object.h already included before system

Comment: @Slava Sorry, I don't understood your comment correctly, because I read it so fast. What did you mean about -system? I can't find this option in gcc documentation. ps. In verbose mode -I for directory with Object.h includes after other include- dirs.

Comment: @serega.mpa ah sorry, -isystem it is. Is there -isystem with Object.h dir before -I?

Comment: @Slava Yes, you absolutely right. But note: ... messages continue to appear.

Answer (score -1):

Taken from here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/547567/want-to-turn-off-note-level-messages-in-gcc

Adding:

```
-fcompare-debug-second
```

to the GCC build string worked for me.